# SQL query to retrieve average of different aggregation type in single query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

This is my data model:

[image]

I need to get name, surname and personal votes average of all students in classroom that have the average lower then the votes average of all students in classroom. Following the desired output:

```
+---------+------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| surname | name |  class |   class_avg |   studend_avg |
+---------+------+--------+-------------+---------------+
| b       | b    |      1 |      4.1250 |        2.7500 |
+---------+------+--------+-------------+---------------+
```

I wrote following query that works correctly in mariadb database:

```
SELECT student.surname, student.name, student.classroom, classroom.average AS classroom_average, AVG(vote.vote) AS student_average
    FROM (student INNER JOIN vote ON student.fiscalcode = vote.fiscalcode)
    INNER JOIN
      (select student.classroom AS classroom, AVG(vote.vote) AS average
      FROM student INNER JOIN vote ON student.fiscalcode = vote.fiscalcode
      GROUP BY student.classroom) AS classroom
    ON student.classroom=classroom.classroom
GROUP BY student.surname, student.name, student.classroom, classroom.average
HAVING AVG(vote.vote) < classroom.average;
```

But I have this error in MS Access:

> Your Query does not include the specified expression "AVG(vote.vote)/AVG(vote.vote) < classroom.average" as part of an aggregate function

There are some other easier method to write this query?

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result. I don't quite understand "votes average of all students in classroom that have the average lower then the votes average of all students in classroom". Aren't these averages the same?

Comment: Sample inserted, thanks! The average aren't the same because the first is the students average, the second is the classroom average. My query is correctly executed in mariadb database but not in MS Access. If i remove the "having" clause there are no error also in MS Access.

Comment: You show desired output but what is source data like? In particular the Vote table. What records would result in the example output?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT StudentAvg.fiscalcode, student.name, student.surname, StudentAvg.AvgOfvote, ClassAvg.AvgOfvote
FROM ((SELECT student.classroom, student.fiscalcode, Avg(vote.vote) AS AvgOfvote
FROM student INNER JOIN vote ON student.fiscalcode = vote.fiscalcode
GROUP BY student.classroom, student.fiscalcode) As StudentAvg INNER JOIN (SELECT student.classroom, Avg(vote.vote) AS AvgOfvote
FROM vote INNER JOIN student ON vote.fiscalcode = student.fiscalcode
GROUP BY student.classroom) AS ClassAvg ON StudentAvg.classroom = ClassAvg.classroom) INNER JOIN student ON StudentAvg.fiscalcode = student.fiscalcode
WHERE (((StudentAvg.AvgOfvote)<[ClassAvg]![AvgOfvote]));
```